# MediaPlayer2 vs MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I started developing simple audio player with MediaPlayer class but I came across [MediaPlayer2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/MediaPlayer2) class. I'm wondering what is the difference between both. Is MediaPlayer2 simply succesor of MediaPlayer and should I use it instead of MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2020, you can read on https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/player/MediaPlayer#setAudioSessionId(int) :

> ... The audio session ID is a system wide unique identifier for the audio stream played by this MediaPlayer2 instance. ...

So it's the doc of Jetpack media2 MediaPlayer but it imply a link between Jetpack MediaPlayer and MediaPlayer2. My bet is that MediaPlayer2 was the previous (or temporary) name of Jetpack MediaPlayer.

So your choice is between using native MediaPlayer (android.media) and Jetpack MediaPlayer (androidx.media2). It's generally advised to use Jetpack one, but be aware that resources (samples or stackoverflow answers for example) about Jetpack media2 are scarce as of April 2020.